# How to list all detected cameras in chrome (offline without a website)?

Tags: browser, webcam, chromium, camera

How can I get chromium to show me a list of all the webcams that it can see?

I do *not* want to use a website. I want something native in chromium that I can use offline without visiting a third party service.

How can I enumerate all of the webcams that my web browser can see?

Answer (score 5):

The `about://settings/content/camera` page has a dropdown that lists the different cameras the browser can see in at least Chrome and Edge.

If you want something more involved, you can try `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` in JS, like in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399845/7411885